# SharePoint 2013 - Site Closure & Deletion not working

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-on-prem, site-deletion, job-definitions

In our project, there is a policy to define deletion of site collection after a couple month.

But when the date for deletion has passed the site collection is still exist.
I checked job definitions and there is a job which name is Dead Site Delete.
Do you think that this job is related to site deletion with policy?
Do you have any idea what could be the possible reasons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Dead Site Delete" job is responsible for the deleting the site collections which full fill the required criteria (which you mentioned in your policy).

The only problem with this job is, Default schedule is run weekly, so you may need to wait for 6 more days. If Policy's deletion date is on Monday then on next Sunday when Timer job run it will delete the site.

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/12/site-use-confirmation-and-deletion-in-sharepoint-2013.html

Comment: We were using this approach to define site collection custom policies. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/site-closure-and-deletion-in-sharepoint-2013/ 
The way you are mentioning is different than our way as far as I understood.
Although running this job manually, It doesn't delete the site collections which supplies our criteria.

Comment: do you want to delete the site collection or you want to delete the subsites?

Comment: I would like to delete site collections with a policy.

Comment: there are 2 timer jobs, mainly "Expiration Policy" timer job which delete the sites after meeting the criteria...But if your site has exchange mailbox attach to it then "Site Policy and Exchange Site Mailbox Policy Update" job will process the mail box as well

Comment: After how many days site is still active? less than 7 days? date fall on late sunday onward?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/oA8sQmQ.png You can see that It has passed almost a year.

Comment: Could you please check the link? May be, there is an issue with the SharePoint Foundation. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_sharepoint-mso_winother/site-deletion-policy-not-deleting-after-the/eb24dd73-34d4-42ef-998a-9ad2c299b743?auth=1

Comment: this is related to Office 365...at this time what i should do, enable the Verbose logging and run the Expiration Policy job. After that look inside the logs for clue. also is the time on the server is correct?

Comment: Yes, the time is correct. I also checked uls logs and there is no issue